# Adding dynamic content to list breaks JQuery Mobile styles

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to dynamically add content to the list :

```
<div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true" id="two">
                <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">
                    Divider
                </li>
                <li data-theme="c">
                    <a href="#page4" data-transition="slide">
                        Element1
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li data-theme="c">
                    <a href="javascript:changePage('1');" data-transition="slide">
                        Element2
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li data-theme="c">
                    <a href="#page1" data-transition="slide">
                        Element3
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

by doing :

```
$("#two").append("<li><a href='#page4'>xxx</a></li>");
$("#two").listview('refresh');
```

but then it breaks the styles. Corners are no longer rounded and on mobile browser page looks like shortened :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fssX9.jpg

Do you have any hints?

thx

Comment: Are you using the last stable version of jquery mobile (v1.0.1)? In [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/v9fhL/) I can't see a rendering problem.

Comment: yep , minified 1.0.1 and jquery 1.6.2 also minified

Answer (score 0):

The LI element in the code below has not data-theme attribute, instead you have it in all other LI

```
$("#two").append("<li><a href='#page4'>xxx</a></li>");
```

Did you try that?:

```
$("#two").append("<li data-theme='c'><a href='#page4'>xxx</a></li>");
```

Comment: I just did. But id didn't help.

Comment: Sorry, sure cannot work because -theme are parsed during the normal JQM page load. And if you try clone an existing LI item and to replace the content into, then add it to page?...

Comment: It actually worked. It is kinda walk around , that I would like to avoid but it looks it is working this way.